# prevent html child element to inherit parent width

Tags: html, css

I have a container for a form with `max-width: 500px` propery.
Inside this container, I have a span element that inherits the parent's width.
Is there a way to prevent this? I have tried to use `position: absolute;` and it solved the width problem but the HTML elements are overlapping.

```
 <div class="form-container">

        <div class="select"> 
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span>
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
....... 
  </div>

.form-container {
   max-width: 500px
}

.select {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hi There !!! You are mentioned about a span element within the container div. But your snippet has a select element within container div :) Please share the right snippet. Also `max-widht: 500px` here should be `max-width:500px;`. It's a typo :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather, thank you, I've made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

`span`s are inline elements by default, which don't react to `width` settings (they are just as wide as their contents, or when those are wide enough, fill their parent element hoizontally).

But you can apply `display: inline-block;` (or `display: block;`) to it and then set a width for it:

```css
.form-container {
  max-width: 500px
}


.select span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">

  <div class="select">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
  .......
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The span element will never inherit parent's width (by itself), unless you have used some other  CSS properties on it. This cannot happen out of blue :)

Or may be your parent is a flex container and you have used `flex:1;` on child.
In which case the child elements will stretch :)